# Native RSA functions in PHP

Tags: php, rsa

I know it's possible to make the keys for RSA using a coded process, but does PHP have any native functions that help with key generation?

Comment: php has lots of crypto libraries available, either integrated in PHP or as external classes ... google it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using openssl_public_encrypt, for this take a look on [page documentation for openssl_public_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php).